# detectEigenFeatures with polygon ROI

Tags: computer-vision

I am using detectEigenFeatures in the Matlab command to obtain the corner points. This function only can provide the corner points within a rectangular boundary region. But I want to extract the corner points within a polygon. I have thought about using small rectangles in order to obtain a polygon. But it seems time-consuming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If corner points are to be found inside a polygonal region of interest using detectEigenFeatures command, it's not possible directly. However, getting all the corner points from the above command, points inside the polygonal ROI can be extracted using the 'inpolygon' command in MATLAB.

Answer (score 0):

Find the bounding box of the polygon.  Find all corner points within the bounding box.  Iterate over the resulting corner points, test each one to see whether it is within the polygon, and if not, throw it away.

Or, implementing your own code to do corner point detection.

Comment: I was trying to find all the corner points within the bounding box. MATLAB's command won't provide the corner points within any polygonal bounding box except rectangles.

Comment: @DebasishJana, please read the definition of bounding box - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_box - I think you're confused.  A bounding box *is* a rectangle.